# Why some commands don't load user environment when executed with ssh? (while other do)

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting, environment-variables, path

On a target machine (OS X El Capitan) I have `brew` in `/usr/local/bin`. When I try to get brew's path I get no result:

```
# ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 which brew
#
```

---

Troubleshooting:

1. `brew` is in `/usr/local/bin/` and executes properly via `ssh`:

   ```
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 ls -l /usr/local/bin/brew
   -rwxr-xr-x  1 vagrant  admin  656 Mar 20 10:05 /usr/local/bin/brew
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 /usr/local/bin/brew --version
   Homebrew 0.9.5 (git revision 3a41; last commit 2016-03-20)
   ```
2. There is `/usr/local/bin` in path:

   ```
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 echo $PATH
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin
   ```
3. `which` itself does not seem to have a problem:

   ```
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 which bash
   /bin/bash
   ```
4. Also when logged interactively to the machine I get the intended result:

   ```
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
   Last login: Sun Mar 20 12:02:55 2016 from 10.0.2.2
   osx-pf:~ vagrant$ which brew
   /usr/local/bin/brew
   ```
5. Finally `which brew` works when in command substitution expression:

   ```
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 echo $(which brew)
   /usr/local/bin/brew
   ```
6. Calling `echo` before `which brew` causes it to give the correct result:

   ```
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 echo test ; which brew
   test
   /usr/local/bin/brew
   ```
7. Calling shell explicitly to run `which brew` does not change the situation:

   ```
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 /bin/sh -c "which\ brew"
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 /bin/sh -c "which\ which"
   /usr/bin/which
   ```

   However with explicit call to `/bin/sh` the "trick" from (6) no longer works:

   ```
   # ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 /bin/sh -c "echo\ test\ \;\ which\ brew"
   test
   #
   ```

---

Why running `which brew` directly as an ssh command argument fails?

Why `echo` which external command in `/bin/echo` sees proper `PATH` while `which` does not? And why running two commands in sequence causes the second one to use environment of the first?

Is it possible to assure the environment would be loaded without referring to undocumented (I presume) workarounds like in (6)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 echo $PATH
```

Your local system's `PATH` will be printed here. You should quote the variable to prevent it from being expanded by the local shell:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 'echo $PATH'
```

The same applies to:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 echo $(which brew)
```

As for:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 echo test ; which brew
```

`which brew` is run after the SSH command ends, by your local shell. That's why this didn't work:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 /bin/sh -c "echo\ test\ \;\ which\ brew"
```

Side note: you don't need to do all that escaping.

---

The problem here might be that you're adding `brew` to your `PATH` in `.profile` (or `.bash_profile` or some similar file), which is run when a **login shell** is started. SSH starts a login shell only when it is run interactively, not when it's told to run a command. From [`man ssh`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ssh.1.html):

```
 If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell
```

You could try:

```
ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 bash -lc brew
```

Comment: That makes sense. One strange thing... There's a difference if I run `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 /bin/bash -lc brew` (ok) and  `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 /bin/sh -lc brew` (brew not found). Both `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` show the same `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`. What could be the reason?

Comment: Bash runs differently when called as `sh`. See [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Invoked-with-name-sh). My guess is that you're setting the `PATH` in `.bash_profile`.

Comment: And I **do** need that escaping... Otherwise it does not work. Does it work for you without?

Comment: `.bash_profile` does not exist. Paths are from `/etc/paths`.

Comment: @techraf since I don't use OSX, that's about all I help you with. It should work without the escaping, but maybe the old version of bash does things differently.

Comment: Checked `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 /bin/sh` and `echo $PATH` from keyboard - indeed there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

When you run commands directly from ssh, you are not "logging in", you are only running a command.

Some shell scripts run when you "log in" - ~/.bashrc,  /etc/profile etc.

`which` uses environment variables - specifically `$PATH` - which may be set in one of these scripts. Without `$PATH`, `which` will not know where to look.

Also, `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 echo $(which brew)` will not give you what you expect - `$(which brew)` is interpreted by the shell, before it even gets to ssh - compare: `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 echo $(hostname)` with `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222 echo '$(hostname)'` (note single quotes around the shell expansion). The first will get the LOCAL hostname, send it to the remote host to be echo'd. The second will be send the `$(hostname)` (literally) to the remote shell, to be expanded there.

UPDATE: I was slightly wrong about this.

When you run a command over ssh, ssh works out if a shell is needed (e.g. working out variables etc. If it is not needed, the binary program is run immediately. Otherwise bash is run, which may set up environment variables etc.

This is why (in your comment) brew --version fails - you don't mention a path. When you `echo...; brew --version`, the semicolon `;` is a special shell character; ssh handles this for you, by running bash for you.

Comment: I'm still far from understanding this... Adding point no. (7) to the question.

Comment: Neither versions of your answer are quite right. SSH always runs a shell, but that shell does not load `/etc/profile` or `~/.profile` if you're running a command rather than starting an interactive session. If the user's login shell is bash and you are running a command, and only on systems where it's enabled (I don't know whether that's the case on OSX), bash loads `~/.bashrc` before executing the command (a bizarre complement to the normal use of `.bashrc`, which is for interactive non-login shells). In all other cases, `.bashrc` is not loaded when logging in over SSH.